# How to install Django if I have my own VPS server with Centos and cpanel/WHM?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, vps, gunicorn

I have a VPS server with Centos and cpanel/WHM.

But I will mount a django app. Do you know a tutorial that can help me?
I heard about mounting Django apps with Nginx & Gunicorn run very good.

But I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good question for StackOverflow since it is very general. Hopefully you can find this useful: http://blog.miki725.com/deploy-django-on-gevent-with-nginx/. If you run across any specific issues you can post another question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you still need the help but I installed it with this tutorial in ubuntu you should try it [here...](http://www.apreche.net/complete-single-server-django-stack-tutorial/)